# Cisco VPN Client For OS X requires a software agreement in place?

Tags: cisco-vpn-client

I am trying to download the latest Cisco VPN Client for OS X. I get

here:http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/macosx/12696

I click to download, I get redirected to Cisco, I create an account, try to download again and they tell me that I need to have a valid technical support agreement to get access to the software.

Really? How do they expect us to VPN into client networks?

Comment: 10.6 has built in Cisco VPN support.

Comment: @moshen - oh, let me check into that.

Comment: @moshen - ah, System Preferences -> Network -> + -> VPN, thanks

Comment: Beyond the built-in support in 10.6, presumably your client that requires you to VPN could provide you with the appropriate version.

Answer (score 1):

System Preferences -> Network -> + -> VPN